# Adding Bootstrap to Rails - @import command not working in application.css.scss file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, sass, bootstrap-sass

I´m just starting with Rails and web developing, I try to follow different tutorials but I get lost when it comes to Bootstrap installation, I add 
gem 'bootstrap-sass' and gem 'autoprefixer-rails' and run bundle install without problem.

But when I modify the application.css.scss file, delete all the comments and type only: @import "bootstrap";  It doesn´t work.

I also noticed that different to the tutorials that I see, when I type @import "*" the phrase color doesn´t change in the editor (like it is not being recognized?).

[This is how it appears on all the tutorials that I find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9zkY.png)

[And this is how it looks in my Sublime Text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCu2V.png)

Could my problem be here? The Editor or the file doesn´t recognize the @import command or is it something else?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you do everything like is here:: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass?

Comment: Do you have [gem `sass`](https://rubygems.org/gems/sass-rails/versions/5.0.4) in your gemfile?

You can [also find it here on github](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails)

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help! Yes, I do it like there, Mateusz, until it comes to "Bower with Rails", that I don´t do.. 

And I have 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3', is it what you ask, SunnyK?

The thing is I tried to follow exactly several youtube tutorials that also only do this first step, not Bower, not Compass... but even so I don´t get same results... 
Can the problem be in the editor? I really wonder why my @import ".." command stays white...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I should close this, I didn´t really solve the problem, I just started from the beginning with a different app and now the @import command IS working, and it does show in red color and Bootstrap is also working..

I still don´t know what was wrong with the first app.. the only thing I did different this time, is that when installing the app I didn´t update rubygems.. I don´t know what else can be different..